# Input.LocationService.isEnabledByUser returning false with Unity Remote in the Editor?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, location

First post on Stack-Overflow, and I sincerely apologize if someone has already asked this, but I searched a lot and couldn't find anyone with a similar issue.

So I just finished setting up my phone (Samsung Galaxy S8) to work with Unity Remote 5, and I set up my location service identification in accordance to the one here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html

My issue is that the script can't seem to get past the !Input.location.isEnabledByUser if statement.

I enabled my location services and high accuracy location is on, which I saw was an issue in another thread. Unity Remote 5 is properly displaying the scene on my phone, but it just doesn't seem to be reading the location data?

Does anybody have any sort of solution for this?
Again I apologize if this was answered elsewhere, or if I'm missing something incredibly trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in your answer is not quite right.

The problem is this first line of the code:

```
if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
    yield break;
```

When you click Play in the Editor, Unity needs few seconds to connect to the Unity Remote. Before those few seconds, `Input.location.isEnabledByUser` will be `false` and `yield break` will execute.

There are two possible ways to fix this:

**1**.Add a delay before that line of code:

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(3)

if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
    yield break;

....
```

**2**.Use [`EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-isRemoteConnected.html) to wait for the Editor to connect to the Unity Remote before moving on.

You have to also wrap it around Unity's [*Platform Dependent directive*](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) so that it will compile for standalone build because this function is from the `UnityEditor` namespace.

```
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
 //Wait until Unity connects to the Unity Remote, while not connected, yield return null
 while (!UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected)
 {
     yield return null;
 }
 #endif

if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
    yield break;

....
```

Comment: I used the second method and that worked for me. Unity 2018.3.9. Unity Remote 5. iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so the fun fact that I didn't notice here is that while Unity Remote 5 uses your device as a *screen*, it doesn't actually treat your device as a mobile device.

This seems really dumb, but I guess I can settle with sometimes doing a full export build when I need to test specific mobile things xD